# Updating User information on Wordpress with Woocommerce?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, admin

I'm currently using Wordpress and 2 plugins
http://www.wpexplorer.com/wordpress-user-contact-fields/
and
Woocommerce

I'm using an endpoint from woocommerce called form-edit-account.php, it lets the user edit his information, however.

The problem is, everytime I press update, everything gets updated properly but the phone number. I added everything inbetween the arterisks.

```
<?php wc_print_notices(); ?>

<form action="" method="post">

    <p class="form-row form-row-first">
        <label for="account_first_name"><?php _e( 'First name', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="input-text" name="account_first_name" id="account_first_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->first_name ); ?>" />
    </p>
    <p class="form-row form-row-last">
        <label for="account_last_name"><?php _e( 'Last name', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="input-text" name="account_last_name" id="account_last_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->last_name ); ?>" />
    </p>
    <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="account_email"><?php _e( 'Email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="email" class="input-text" name="account_email" id="account_email" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->user_email ); ?>" />
    </p>
    <p class="form-row form-row-first">
        <label for="password_1"><?php _e( 'Password (leave blank to leave unchanged)', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
        <input type="password" class="input-text" name="password_1" id="password_1" />
    </p>
    <p class="form-row form-row-last">
        <label for="password_2"><?php _e( 'Confirm new password', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
        <input type="password" class="input-text" name="password_2" id="password_2" />
    </p>
    *****************
    <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="account_phone"><?php _e( 'Phone', 'woocommerce' ); ?> </label>
        <input type="text" class="input-text" name="phone" id="phone" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->phone ); ?>" />
    </p>
    *****************
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <p><input type="submit" class="button" name="save_account_details" value="<?php _e( 'Save changes', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" /></p>

    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'save_account_details' ); ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="save_account_details" />
</form>
```

Is there anyway to keep using woocommerce to update this custom info? Sorry I'm new both to woocommerce and to user based websites.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@doublesharp

There are a few errors in your code.

```
update_usermeta
```

is in fact

```
update_user_meta
```

and

```
add_action("save_account_details",...
```

should be

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_account_details',...
```

so the full code should be

```
function save_additional_account_details( $user_ID ){
    $phone = ! empty( $_POST['phone'] ) ? wc_clean( $_POST['phone'] ) : '';
    update_user_meta( $user_ID, 'phone', $phone );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_account_details', 'save_additional_account_details' );
```

Took me a little trial&error to figure this out, but you gave me a right track, thanks!

Cheers,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

The [`save_account_details()`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-form-handler.php#L137) function handles the form processing for `form-edit-account.php`. Once the default save is completed without errors, there is an action hook called [`woocommerce_save_account_details`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-form-handler.php#L225) that you can use to save further information - it takes only the user ID as an argument, but the rest of the info is available in the `$_POST`.

```
function save_additional_account_details( $user_ID ){
    $phone = ! empty( $_POST['phone'] ) ? wc_clean( $_POST['phone'] ) : '';
    update_usermeta( $user_ID, 'phone', $phone );
}
add_action( 'save_account_details', 'save_additional_account_details' );
```

You also have a couple of issues with the code you added to the page:

- The `for` attribute of the `<label>` tag has to match the `name` of the `<input>` tag, so "phone"
- There is no reason to `_e( 'Phone', 'woocommerce' );` unless "Phone" exists in the WooCommerce translations
- You need to access the current value (which is going to be stored as User MetaData) using [`get_usermeta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_usermeta).
- You should copy this file to one of your own name if you are going to modify it - upgrades to WooCommerce may overwrite your changes.

Your additional code should look like the following.

```
<p class="form-row form-row-wide">
    <label for="phone">Phone</label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text" name="phone" id="phone" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_usermeta( $user->ID, 'phone' ) ); ?>" />
</p>
```