# How to update billing_city data in woocommerce from facebook?

Tags: wordpress, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm making users sign up through facebook on my woo commerce. 
Also, I'm able to update first_name, last_name, email, id in WordPress wp_update_user.
But unable to fetch city in billing_city. How it could be done. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.
Code which I used is:

```
$user = apply_filters( 'fbl/user_data_login', array(
    'fb_user_id'   => $fb_user['id'],
    'first_name'   => $fb_user['first_name'],
    'last_name'    => $fb_user['last_name'],
    'user_email'   => $fb_user['email'],
    'billing_city' => $fb_user['location'],
    'user_url'     => $fb_user['link'],
    'user_pass'    => wp_generate_password(),
));
```

Comment: Anyone there who can help me.

Comment: `billing_city` cannot be saved with wp_update_user. You have to look for the meta-fields. Maybe this could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24171975/updating-user-information-on-wordpress-with-woocommerce

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide me any code for the same. @CodeBrauer